# В чем ошибка создания тригера?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CreatePhotoAlbumUser` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO usersalbums Set 
   UsersAlbumsName = 'Diplomas, awards, certificates', 
   UsersAlbumsTime = NEW.UsersTime, 
   UsersAlbumsType = 1,
   UsersAlbumsIdToUser = NEW.idUsers;
END
```

Ругается здесь на кавычки: UsersAlbumsName = 'Diplomas, awards, certificates',

Comment: А какой тип у UsersAlbumsName?

Comment: varchar(150)

Comment: Никто не знает?

Answer (score 4):

[Смотрим](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) на синтаксис создания триггера:

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    TRIGGER trigger_name
    trigger_time trigger_event
    ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW
    trigger_body

trigger_time: { BEFORE | AFTER }

trigger_event: { INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE }
```

Ваш код вроде соответствует указанному синтаксису:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CreatePhotoAlbumUser` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usersalbums Set 
    UsersAlbumsName = 'Diplomas, awards, certificates', 
    UsersAlbumsTime = NEW.UsersTime, 
    UsersAlbumsType = 1,
    UsersAlbumsIdToUser = NEW.idUsers;
END
```

В чем же проблема?

А дело в том, что mysql выполняет команду как только вы ввели ее полностью.

Что значит "ввели ее полностью"? Это значит, что вы набрали какую-то команду и завершили ее разделителем команд. По дефолту этим разделителем является знак `;` (точка с запятой)

Т.е. на самом деле `mysql` думает что вы ввели команду

```
CREATE TRIGGER `CreatePhotoAlbumUser` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usersalbums Set 
    UsersAlbumsName = 'Diplomas, awards, certificates', 
    UsersAlbumsTime = NEW.UsersTime, 
    UsersAlbumsType = 1,
    UsersAlbumsIdToUser = NEW.idUsers;
```

Очевидно, эта команда не валидна.

Как же тогда правильно указать команду в триггере? Для этого [существует](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html) специальный синтаксис смены разделителя команд:

```
DELIMITER DELIMITER_CHAR
```

Таким образом, если изменить разделитель команд, то `mysql` будет воспринимать нашу команду как одно целое. Главное - не забыть завершить нашу конструкцию новым разделителем (чего у вас, кстати, нет) и вернуть наш старый разделитель на место.

В итоге получаем, что для создания триггера необходим следующий код:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `CreatePhotoAlbumUser` AFTER INSERT ON `user`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO usersalbums Set 
    UsersAlbumsName = 'Diplomas, awards, certificates', 
    UsersAlbumsTime = NEW.UsersTime, 
    UsersAlbumsType = 1,
    UsersAlbumsIdToUser = NEW.idUsers;
END
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Теперь, после `DELIMITER |` знак `;` не является разделителем команд и `mysql` не выдаст ошибку когда встретит этот знак. После создания нашего триггера возвращаем старый разделитель команд `;` (точку с запятой)