# Ошибка создания триггера

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Delete Video` AFTER DELETE ON video 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM usersalbumsvideo where id_video = OLD.idVideo; 
DELETE FROM categorytovideo where idVideo = OLD.idVideo; 
END
```

Название полей правильное.
Ошибка на строке 4

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server
> version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 4

Comment: Пробовал менять местами `id_video = OLD.idVideo`, а так же один DELETE

Comment: А разделить (delimiter) изменить не пробовали? Посмотри примеры [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Они как раз и меняются для того, чтобы можно было его использовать в теле функций/триггеров.

UPD: не "его", а точку запятой в запросах внутри функции

Comment: Пробовал и разделители - тоже не сработало

Comment: Внешние ключи с каскадным удалением решат проблему без триггеров. :-)

Comment: Можно подробней о каскадном удалении?

Comment: Не заметил, что удаляете.

Небольшой [туториал](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/), [документация на русском](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SEC451.html)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем ошибка создания тригера?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275409/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)