# Ошибка при создании процедуры MySql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE procedure my_proc(OUT rcount INT)  BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `todo`; END;
```

Вылетает ошибка  -

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''

Comment: мануал читал ? гуглил ? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: sorry не сразу нашел нужную инфу. Спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [В чем ошибка создания тригера?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/275409/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)